# Get data from AJAX API and display it in HTML document

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I'm doing some troubleshooting on some API code.

We want to take from the XML format brought back in the API call and convert it into JSON.  To help me work through this manipulation, I want to see what the data looks like, so I'm simply trying to get it to print into the body of an HTML document. Here is the HTML code which shows nothing, but Response Data when opened in a browser:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2> Response Data </h2>
    <!-- AJAX API Call -->

    <script> 
    {
        var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "https://qualysapi.qg2.apps.qualys.com/api/2.0/fo/scan/?action=list",
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                "Authorization": "#############################################",
                "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            }
        }

        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
            $('body').append(response);
        });
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It wouldn't show on the page as you are using `console.log`, that gets printed to the console (F12, console tab)

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is due to not being authorized, but I get a [302 redirect](https://qualysguard.qg2.apps.qualys.com/qwebhelp/fo_portal/api/notification1.htm). `Be sure to specify the header with your API request. This syntax must be included: "-H X-Requested-With: <user description, like a user agent>"`

Comment: @showdev, thats probably because I changed the authorization to just ###### for security reasons.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I actually looked in the console before to see if I got an errors.  I did not see anything displayed or have an errors

Comment: @NJ13 Agreed. Unfortunately, this will be difficult to troubleshoot without authentication.

Comment: If you didn't say anything displayed than either your request never completed or your ajax call was never made in the first place. You will need to do more debugging to pin point the problem. With the snippet you got though you should at least be getting an undefined error as you havent included jQuery

Comment: Kafoso makes a good point. Did you include the jQuery library?

Comment: @showdev I did not, but I will.

Answer (score 1):

console.log() outputs the information to the browser console (developer tools). You need to direct the output to an element on the page. The following, using JQuery, appends the response to the body element:

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    $('body').append(response);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` outputs things in the Console/Developer Tools. Not inside the HTML (DOM).

What you want to do is manipulate the DOM. The placement of your Javascript code does not mean it will be output within the `<body>` tag.

What you need is to iterate over the contents of your `response` object (should be JSON or XML), and then append nodes of text or even children DOM nodes to the `<body>` tag.

Also, the `$.ajax` function, you are utilizing, uses the [jQuery library](https://jquery.com/). So you need to include that - either a local copy or via a CDN - in your `<head>` tag. Or at least before you call it in your custom Javascript code.

This is very fundamental and you can easily find many guides via Google on how to implement this.

Comment: I added the CDN to the header, but still not seeing anything.  I'm going to look into the API call more and see what the issue is. Also, thanks for the info on iterating over the response.  Once, I am able to get the API to return data that was my next step